# switch state in the FlipsideViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

in my app i have a switch in the flipsideview when i set it to on all work properly then i touch Done to return to the main view, now when i touch again the info button it appear off till now no problem but if i touch Done button (without touch the switch) it will called the function with off statement **my question is how to check if the switch (on FlipsideView) is on let it on** where i should write my code maybe i'll do it by myself but where to write the code

Answer (score 0):

You could store the state as a member variable, then update the UI in viewWillAppear:animated:. For example, in `FlipsideViewController.h` file, declare a member variable called `switchIsOn`:

```
@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController {
    BOOL switchIsOn;
    // Other member variables here
}

@property (nonatomic) BOOL switchIsOn;
```

Then in `FlipsideViewController.m`:

```
@synthesize switchIsOn;

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.switch setOn:self.switchIsOn animated:NO];
}
```

You can set the value of self.switchIsOn in response to the switch being toggled. e.g. create a method like this:

```
-(IBAction)handleSwitch:(id)sender {
    self.switchIsOn = self.switch.on;
}
```

and then bind that method to the switch's Value Changed event.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hello thanks for the answer but what the type of  storedvalue i got an  error: request for member 'storedValue' in something not a structure or union" some help plz

Comment: You need to declare the property too. I've updated my answer to show that bit.

Comment: ok now when i pressed the info button the switch is off click to on done all work properly, but if click the info second time it is off again